# Unable to boot into Recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, asus-zenfone-3

I was using the latest build for my device: Aex Pie.
https://downloads.aospextended.com/Z010D

It has a bug : while we try to reboot it will get stuck in black screen same with power off. The developer who made this rom don't know how to fix that

The only solution I found is this :

For reboot =  Press <kbd>power</kbd> button ~5 sec

For Recovery = Press <kbd>power</kbd> button ~5 sec when vibration comes then press <kbd>volume down</kbd> button when asus logo comes then release <kbd>power</kbd> button only.

They say its EDL bug which is something gone wrong in kernel source.

Device descriptions are given below
Device : Asus Zenfone Max ZC550KL

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

(Tap to enlarge)

Comment: You are welcome. We all were first time users !